# Using the exact same OS to virtualize and dualboot

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, multi-boot

I want to be able to run a guest Windows 7 VM on my host OS X system and then be able to shut down my entire computer and boot that exact same Windows 7 system and pick up exactly where I left off in the VM except now obviously using all of my computer's resources just for Windows 7.

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: This sounds like using a raw disk partition in a VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to pay attention to:

1. Your VM software needs to support using the Raw disk. This is going to depend on your VM software and version.
2. Hibernation or sleep mode *will not work* when switching between the VM and real life
3. You will need to install the VM drivers for the hard drive controller, and the drivers for the controller physically attached to the PC.

I have not seen any that will *seemlessly* go back and forth multiple times, but I have seen VM products that will go P2V (Physical to Virtual).

Although this is not a complete answer, it should give you a better idea of what to search for in your product.